How to add a dynamic dependent select dropdown shad cn
so I'm trying to have a dropdown select option (sub-category) that depends on another select component (category).
So far, I have been able to dynamically populate the dependent select option (sub-category) with useEffect and useState.
My only problem is when I select a sub category like 'Watches' under Fashion and then switch the parent select component to the Art category, the sub category select component shows a blank state instead of the default placeholder. I don't know if someone can understand this but I'm kind of stuck here
This is the trigger for the filters
<SheetContent className="px-2 h-full flex flex-col overflow-y-scroll max-w-[300px] mobile_menu" side={'left'}>
                    <div className='flex justify-between w-full border-b pb-2.5 items-center flex-shrink-0'>
                        <SheetHeader className='text-left border-neutral-200'>
                            <SheetTitle className="text-gray-600">Filter</SheetTitle>
                        </SheetHeader>
                        <SheetClose className='text-muted-foreground hover:text-red-300'>
                            <X size={20} />
                        </SheetClose>
                    </div>
                    <Form {...form}>
                        <form
                            className=""
                        >
                            <div className='space-y-3'>
                                <FormField
                                    control={form.control}
                                    name="category"
                                    render={({ field }) => (
                                        <FormItem>
                                            <FormLabel className="text-gray-600 text-xs">Category</FormLabel>
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <Select defaultValue='' onValueChange={handleCategoryChange}>

                                                    <SelectTrigger>
                                                        <SelectValue placeholder="Select a category" />
                                                    </SelectTrigger>
                                                    <SelectContent>
                                                        <SelectGroup className='space-y-1'>
                                                            <SelectItem value='' className='data-[highlighted]:bg-blue-100 data-[state=checked]:bg-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-50'>
                                                                ---
                                                            </SelectItem>
                                                            {categories.map((category) => (
                                                                <SelectItem key={category.id} value={category.id} className={cn('data-[highlighted]:bg-blue-100 data-[state=checked]:bg-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-50', category.name == 'Square' && 'hidden')}>
                                                                    {category.name}
                                                                </SelectItem>
                                                            ))}
                                                        </SelectGroup>

                                                    </SelectContent>
                                                </Select>
                                            </FormControl>
                                            <FormMessage />
                                        </FormItem>
                                    )}
                                />

                                <FormField
                                    control={form.control}
                                    name="subCategory"
                                    render={({ field }) => (
                                        <FormItem>
                                            <FormLabel className="text-gray-600 text-xs">Sub-Category</FormLabel>
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <Select defaultOpen>
                                                    <SelectTrigger>
                                                        <SelectValue placeholder="Select a sub-category" />
                                                    </SelectTrigger>
                                                    <SelectContent>
                                                        <SelectGroup className='space-y-1'>
                                                            <SelectItem value='' defaultChecked className='data-[highlighted]:bg-blue-100 data-[state=checked]:bg-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-50'>
                                                                ---
                                                            </SelectItem>

                                                            <>
                                                                <SubCategoryFilter data={selectedSubCategory} />
                                                            </>
                                                        </SelectGroup>

                                                    </SelectContent>
                                                </Select>
                                                {/* <div className="flex relative">
                                                    <select name="subCategory" id="subCategory" className='appearance-none h-9 w-full items-center justify-between  shadow-sm ring-offset-background px-3 py-2 border-input whitespace-nowrap rounded-md border bg-transparent text-sm placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus:outline-none disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50 cursor-pointer focus:ring-1 focus:ring-ring'>
                                                        <option value="" defaultChecked>Select a sub category</option>
                                                        {selectedSubCategory.map((subCategory) => (
                                                            <option value={subCategory.id} key={subCategory.id}>
                                                                {subCategory.name}
                                                            </option>
                                                        ))}
                                                    </select>

                                                    <CaretSortIcon className="h-4 w-4 opacity-50 absolute right-3 top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 -z-10" />
                                                </div> */}

                                            </FormControl>
                                            <FormMessage />
                                        </FormItem>
                                    )}
                                />

                                {/* <FormField
                                    control={form.control}
                                    name="country"
                                    render={({ field }) => (
                                        <FormItem>
                                            <FormLabel className="text-gray-600 text-xs">Country</FormLabel>
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <Select defaultValue=''>

                                                    <SelectTrigger>
                                                        <SelectValue placeholder="Select a location" />
                                                    </SelectTrigger>
                                                    <SelectContent>
                                                        <SelectGroup className='space-y-1'>
                                                            <SelectItem value='' className='data-[highlighted]:bg-blue-100 data-[state=checked]:bg-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-50'>
                                                                ---
                                                            </SelectItem>
                                                            {categories.map((category) => (
                                                                <SelectItem key={category.id} value={category.id} className={cn('data-[highlighted]:bg-blue-100 data-[state=checked]:bg-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-50', category.name == 'Square' && 'hidden')}>
                                                                    {category.name}
                                                                </SelectItem>
                                                            ))}
                                                        </SelectGroup>

                                                    </SelectContent>
                                                </Select>
                                            </FormControl>
                                            <FormMessage />
                                        </FormItem>
                                    )}
                                /> */}
                            </div>

                        </form>

                    </Form>
                </SheetContent>

This is the state management and useEffect function I used to populate it.
const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState('');
    const [selectedSubCategory, setSelectedSubCategory] = useState<SubCategory[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const filteredStates = subCategories.filter(subCategory => subCategory.categoryId == selectedCategory);
        setSelectedSubCategory(filteredStates)
    }, [selectedCategory])

My main issue lies when I select a sub category and then switch to another sub category. The sub category becomes empty which I don't want. The sub categories are being populated but that strikes me as a bug
